# Thread-safe updating of a cached resource

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, guava

The logic is pretty straightforward:

```java
Foo foo = cache.get();
if (isUpToDate(foo)) {
    return foo;
} else {
    foo = getUpdatedFoo(); // slow or expensive
    cache.put(foo);
    return foo;
}
```

However, I want to make sure that

1. only one thread calls `getUpdatedFoo()` at a time
2. if thread A is already calling `getUpdatedFoo()`, thread B doesn't
   call it, instead just waiting for thread A's results

I could probably cobble together something based on the Memoizer pattern from JCiP, but I suspect there's a simpler way -- possibly using Guava CacheBuilder? Not immediately obvious how, though.

---

**Update:** Implemented a double-checked locking pattern per [FrankPL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18411617/27358) below:

```java
Foo foo = cache.get();
if (!isUpToDate(foo)) {
    lock.lock(); // Will block if some other thread is refreshing
    try {
        // See if some other thread already refreshed for us
        foo = cache.get();
        if (!isUpToDate(foo)) {
            // guess not, we'll refresh it ourselves
            foo = getUpdatedFoo();
            cache.put(foo);
        }
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
return foo;
```

Comment: You could designate a single thread to do cache refreshing in the background.

Comment: Have you considered [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) - it really is as simple as it looks.

Comment: @Gray I could, but as long as the client threads would be blocking waiting for that thread anyway, I'd rather have one of them do the work.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon simple as it is, ehcache is *massively* more complicated than I need for this use case.

Comment: Do they need to block waiting for the update or could the background thread just run every X minutes or something and update those entries that are out of date?

Comment: That doesn't help if they arrive between updates, and if they need the data, they'll need it now.

Comment: What logic did you use to check if the cache is up-to-date?

Comment: @Kristy it's been so long since I wrote this I can't remember what actual problem I was trying to solve, but it would have been something application-specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking for the double checked locking pattern that you could use. Instead of the `new Helper()` used in the code samples, use your `getUpdatedFoo()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider a Read-write lock (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html). A sample code is given below:

```
rwlock.readLock().lock();
Foo foo = cache.get();
if(isUpToDate(foo)) {
    rwlock.readLock.unlock();
    return foo;
} else {
    rwlock.readLock.unlock();
    rwlock.writeLock.lock();
    // recheck if updated
    Foo foo = cache.get();
    if(isUpToDate(foo)) {
        rwlock.writeLock.unlock();
        return foo;
    } else {
        foo = getUpdatedFoo();
        cache.put(foo);
        rwlock.writeLock.unlock();
        return foo;
    }
}
```